# If one ClickHouse replica is down, how long operation log can keep in ZooKeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, clickhouse

Under my understanding, in ClickHouse ReplicatedMergeTree, insert operation will write log in ZK "/log", other replica pull log, execute task and sync date.

My question is when one replica is unavailable(machine is down or clickhouse instance is down), this replica cannot pull log and sync data. If other replica still insert data and push log to ZK. How long the operation log will keep in ZK? Is there valid period? Maybe ZK will not keep these log forever, is there exact keep time?

And if insert log in ZK is removed and the prior unavailable replica is normal again, how this replica sync data with other replica?

Appreciate for any answer or discussion, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM system.merge_tree_settings
WHERE name LIKE '%replicated_logs%'
FORMAT Vertical

Query id: 534466cf-1624-4ca0-b559-bc8c381ff547

Row 1:
──────
name:        max_replicated_logs_to_keep
value:       1000
changed:     0
description: How many records may be in log, if there is inactive replica. Inactive replica becomes lost when when this number exceed.
type:        UInt64

Row 2:
──────
name:        min_replicated_logs_to_keep
value:       10
changed:     0
description: Keep about this number of last records in ZooKeeper log, even if they are obsolete. It doesn't affect work of tables: used only to diagnose ZooKeeper log before cleaning.
type:        UInt64
```

max_replicated_logs_to_keep now is 1000.
During the past this default value were changing, it was 10000, 100, 1000 :) .

If a replication log is "rotated" (a replica delay is >1000), it's not a problem at all, the stale replica starts a special bootstrap procedure, it does not use log at all, but it syncs it's metadata and a list of parts with other replicas, this procedure is slightly longer than rolling the log.

Comment: Thank you a lot, It's very helpful, clear for me now.